# How to see the percentage of complete work in current iteration in TFS?

Tags: tfs-2015

We need to display a chart that displays the pecentage of completed work for several projects in some project collection, lets say, the well known **DefualtCollection**. So if for example we have 3 projects in the collection, projects **1**, **2** and **3**, and project **1** has completed 30% of its tasks, **2** has completed 57%, and **3** has completed 20% of its tasks, I want to the chart to display something like this:
[image]

Each project has its own area path. How can we achive this?

Comment: If percentage is not possible, showing the number of remaining work items (work items that are not in a final state like Done, Finished etc) next to, or below (stacked) the total work items is also fine. Even better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use excel report based on the warehouse in TFS. The reporting warehouse is a traditional data warehouse that consists of a relational database and an Analysis Services database.

More details please refer: [Manage the data warehouse and analysis services cube](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/manage-reports-data-warehouse-cube)