# TFS Custom Widget that shows the completion percentage for all Projects

Tags: tfs

can I create an Extension/Widget on projects home page beside "Recent projects & teams" and "Recent team rooms" ? if yes, then

How can I develop a custom TFS widget that shows the completion percentage of all defined projects in TFS?

for example: project A = 30%, project B = 50%, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported according to the official document, we can only create extension within Collection. See [Extension points - Targetable hub groups](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/targets/overview#targetable-hub-groups)

You can refer to this article to [Monitor progress and trends](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/monitor-progress-trends).

To see the percentage of complete work in iteration for specific project in TFS, you could use excel report based on the warehouse in TFS. Reference this thread :

[How to see the percentage of complete work in current iteration in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866680/how-to-see-the-percentage-of-complete-work-in-current-iteration-in-tfs)

---

**UPDATE:**

You can create a query to get all the work items with the state in your project. Then export the query to excel, them create the chart or table in excel based on the work item state to calculate and display the completion percentage.

eg : All 10 work items, Done 5, then the completion percentage should be 50%.

Just create table/chart in Excel manually.

Below articles for your reference:

- [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel)
- [Create Excel reports from a work item query](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/excel/create-status-and-trend-excel-reports)

Comment: I read the link "How to see the percentage of complete work in current iteration in TFS?" but I couldn't figure out from where to start, could you please send a snapshots of steps to create the chart

Comment: @Samirovic That's just for your reference, I mean you can export the query or all work items with the state, them create the chart or table in excel based on the work item state to display the completion percentage. See the updated answer for more information.

Comment: I'm looking for a page inside the TFS to do the reporting, this page will be used by the business people so the export thing (offline/disconnected) will not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot achieve that as mentioned in above answer.